# Flattening columns into rows

Tags: sql

I am selecting some columns from a table and adding some new columns (such as birthday and school address) with default values l

```
select 
    s.id,
    s.address,
    Birthday as null,
    School_Address as 'Mumbai'
from student s;
```

But I am getting an error. Can someone tell me the right approach to assign these values.

Comment: Birthday as null is renaming the column name : Birthday to Null. So this syntax will not be helpful. Null Birthday is actually assigning null value to the column : Birthday.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it the wrong way round. First comes the value then the alias not the other way.

```
SELECT s.id,
       s.address,
       NULL birthday, 
       'Mumbai' school_address
       FROM student s;
```